# value does not enter the switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

I  have an ecommerce website project , and here is the detail,it is just tiny problem i can not fix it . I have 2 tables first table called items , second table is cart. I ve link called Add to cart in one page which transform me to cart.php

`a href="cart.php? action=add & id=<?php echo $itemId; ?>"> Add to Cart </a><br/>`

```
'<a href="cart.php? action=show & id=<?php echo $itemId; ?> ">View Shopping Cart </a>`
```

afther that i've cart.php page:

```
  <?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Cart Page </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include "function.php";
ConnectToDb( );
$id= $_GET['id'];
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
$action=(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != '') ? $_GET['action'] : 'view';

switch($action){
case "add":
{$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemId='$id'");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
 $itemPrice= $row["itemPrice"];
 $itemName= $row["itemName"];
 $quanty=$row["qty"];

$query="insert into cart values('1',".$_GET[id].",1,".$itemPrice.",".$itemName.")";
$result=mysql_query($query);
header("location:cart.php? action=show ");
echo "Item Was Added";
break;
}
case "remove":
{
$query="delete from cart where itemId=".$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query($query);
header("location:cart.php?action=show");
}

case "update":
{
$query="update cart set". $quanty = $_POST['quantity']."where itemId=".$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query($query);
header("location:cart.php?action=show");
break;
}
case "show_update":
{
$result = mysql_query("select * from cart");
$uid=$row["uid"];
$itemId= $row["itemId"];
$qty=$row["qty"];
$itemPrice=  $row["itemPrice"];
$itemName=  $row["itemName"];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   if ($itemId == $id )
    {  
            $totalCost =0;
            $query = "select * from cart inner join items on cart.itemId= items.itemId";    
            $result = mysql_query($query); 
            echo "<table width ='100%' border ='1'>"; 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {$totalCost += ($qty * $itemPrice);
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";    echo $itemName;     echo "</td>";
            echo "<td> SR"; echo $itemPrice;    echo "</td>";
            echo "<td> <input type ='text' name='quantity' value=".$qty."</td>";
            echo'<td width="23%"><a href="cart.php?action=update&id='.$itemId.'">save</a></td>';
            echo'<td width="23%"><a href="cart.php?action=remove&id='.$itemId.'">Remove</a></td>';
            echo"</tr>";}
            // Increment the total cost of all items
            $totalCost += ($row["qty"] * $row["itemPrice"]);
            echo "<tr> <td colspan='2'> <a href='products.php'>Keep Shopping</a></td>";
            echo "<td colspan='2'> <b>Total: SR".$totalCost."</b></td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            }
        else{   
            $totalCost =0;
            $query2 = "select * from cart inner join items on cart.itemId= items.itemId";   
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2); 
            echo "<table width ='100%' border ='1'>"; 
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
            {$totalCost += ($row2["qty"] * $row2["itemPrice"]);
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";    echo $row2['itemName'];     echo "</td>";
            echo "<td> SR"; echo $row2["itemPrice"];    echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";     echo $row2["qty"];         echo "</td>";
            echo'<td width="23%"><a href="cart.php?action=show_update&id='.$row2["itemId"].">edit</a></td>";
            echo'<td width="23%"><a href="cart.php?action=remove&id='.$row2["itemId"].">Remove</a></td>";
            echo"</tr>";
            }
            // Increment the total cost of all items
            $totalCost += ($row2["qty"] * $row2["itemPrice"]);
            echo "<tr> <td colspan='2'> <a href='homestore.php'>Keep Shopping</a></td>";
            echo "<td colspan='2'> <b>Total: SR".$totalCost."</b></td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";}
            break;
}}
case "show":
{
$totalCost =0;
$query = "select * from cart inner join items on cart.itemId = items.itemId";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<table width="100%" border="1"> 
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
    $totalCost += ($row["qty"] * $row["itemPrice"]);
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["itemName"]; ?></td>
    <td>SR<?php echo $row["itemPrice"]; ?></td>
    <td><a href="cart.php?action=show_update&id=<?php echo $row["itemId"]; ?>">edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="cart.php?action=remove&id=<?php echo $row["itemId"]; ?>">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php } 

// Increment the total cost of all items
$totalCost += ($row["qty"] * $row["itemPrice"]);
$totalCost = $totalCost + ($row["qty"] * $row["itemPrice"]); ?>
<tr> <td colspan="2"> <a href="products.php">Keep Shopping</a></td>
<td colspan="2"> <b>Total: SR<?php echo $totalCost; ?></b></td></tr>
</table>

<?php break; }
}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the idea if the user click the link the action = "add" and id of product will transfare to cart.php,
the problem is $action can not insert into Switch statment eventhough I've 
echo $action and it print add 
I do not know why it doesnot enter the switch statment 
also I 've tried to echo $id and it print 2 which is correct 
I've tried var_dump($_GET) and also it works it shows me that there is string add and id =2
I want to be crasy because I am setting on the latop 2 full day and it is not work .

Here I do not interset with session of the cart nor the user that is why in add case i insert 1 as first value for uid just now , if it work success i'll add the sessions.
after add to card is pressed it will transfer directly to show case where we find edit and remove 
of course pressing remove in the show case it will transfer him to remove case 
however

if he press edit link in show case it will transfer him to showupdate case where he can edit the quantity , if id match id text box will generate other products will not have text box, by default quantity will be 1 if textbox wasgenerated save link it will appear which transform him update case where we update the quantity in cart table.

I just want to know why the `$action` not get enter to switch statment ??

Comment: Its possible that the `ConnectToDb( )` function doesn't return or fails silently.  Put a print statement after it to ensure you're returning from it.  Also, you should add a default case (see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)) to see if you're not matching a case correctly.

Comment: Another episode of [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: for debugging purposes try adding a default to the switch and in it print the value of $action

Comment: I'm sorry, but can't help wondering: whether all your links really written this way in the code: cart.php? action=add & id=2 (i mean, with whitespace around params)?

Comment: here is the problem if i remove the spaces in the link

Comment: action=add & id=2  , it doesnot know  $id  and output undefinef innex id in $id=$_GeT['id'] .. if i remove spaces it will not transfer the id

Comment: should i remove the space at the link ??

Comment: If I removoe space at link $action=null + undefind index id

Answer (score 0):

echo $action after this line

```
$action=(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != '') ? $_GET['action'] : 'view';
```

and check its value

Comment: it print add that means it works but still not enter to the case

Comment: Then try the following just to check if the codes inside the switch cause this: switch($action){
case "add": echo "Add";break; case "delete":echo "delete";break; case "update":echo "update";break;}

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what these lines do:

```
'<a href="cart.php? action=show & id=<?php echo $itemId; ?> ">View Shopping Cart </a>`
```

and

```
$action=(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != '') ? $_GET['action'] : 'view';
```

If not, I humbly suggest that you think about purchasing a ecommerce solution or using an open source option.

If you do, then you should see that this is actually where your error stems from since you have spaces in the query string.

Also, since you don't have either a `view` branch or `default` branch, you're skipping the entire `switch` statement.

Comment: It's quite easy to check, though, by debugging the `$action === 'action '` case.

Comment: `$_GET['action']` won't exist, `$_GET[' action']` will.  The second note about $action is just pointing out that he is "defaulting" $action to "view", but not handling it in the switch statement, nor using a default branch.

Comment: Yes, it's quite logical; but how he gets 'add' printed then? ) Probably 'add ' (that's the only explanation why switch works wrong when it should be right )), but still...

Comment: First of all , I am student at university , I am not purchacing any code , if you want give help , do it , if not , I hope someone else help me . Second I am who wrote those code as our instructor teach us , she is instructor , but she doesnot test her code ,Thank you . i will try

Comment: I have tried to put default , then it always go to default case , however it's value is add and there is case add

Comment: If it always goes to the default case, then it's not matching -- in the default case add `printf('[%s]',$action);` and **copy and paste** what it says

Comment: it says [add] as I said to you if i remove the space betweean action & id it doesnot transfer id to cart.php and it says undefined index at $id=$_GET['id']

Comment: did you copy and paste the [add] ? or just re-type?  **copy and paste please***.  And yes, there should be no spaces in the query string.

Comment: I've add default case as you said ... I 've copy it and paste in default case the output undefined index id and it print null

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution; you will laugh if you kow the answer. It is:

It should not start with   `$id= $_GET['id'];`
because in the link "Add"to cart" the action comes first then the `id`.
I've removed   `$id= $_GET['id'];`  from the begining, and I placed it inside each case, and it is working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

change `$_GET[id]` to `$id` as you are already receiving this in $id

Comment: Do you expect this to address his issue?

Comment: this should work , as he is asking about value not getting inserted in switch statement . Why do you doubt , if I may ask ?

Comment: How is that work I must get it from product page , as i did in $action

Comment: where is the break  after this  case "remove":
{
$query="delete from cart where itemId=".$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query($query);
header("location:cart.php?action=show");
}